# How to assign class level data in a TestNG unit test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I am using TestNG as my Java testing framework, and I have the need for a given test class to maintain some state which will be used by several of the test methods.  Specifically, I would like this state to be initialized once, before any tests are run, but then have it be available to any subsequent test in the class.

From what I read, the `@BeforeClass` annotation can be added to a method, which will run before any tests are run.  However, I have been noticing very strange behavior.  Consider the following sample code, which is a distilled version of my actual setup:

```
public class MyTestClass {
    private static String[][] array;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        array = new String[][] {{"A", "B", "C"},{"D", "E", "F"},{"G", "H", "I"}};
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        // use 'array'
        // but the data might be corrupted
    }
}
```

The above is a simplification, but what I have noticed is that `static` variables which I initialize in the `@BeforeClass` method appear to be having their values changed later on.

What is the proper way of setting up some shared/static state for a TestNG unit test?

Comment: Your setup looks fine - can you provide an example that reproduces the incorrect result? (you don't modify the array in your tests, right?)

Comment: @assylias I'm not posting the full code because it is too long.  What I will tell you is that previously I had getter helper methods which each returned a 2D array in common use by several tests.  i thought it would be a good idea to reuse things, hence my attempt to use a `@BeforeTest` method.

Comment: What I observed is that the values of the arrays seem to just change to random values.  This of course causes the tests to break.  For now, I am reverting to safer code.

Comment: Unittest methods should not depend on each other in any way and therefor should not share any *state*!

Comment: @TimothyTruckle This sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unittest methods should not depend on each other in any way and therefor should not share any *state*!

Comment: I am marking this as the tentative correct answer as unit tests should ideally be stateless and independent.

Answer (score 0):

A static variable may be initialized multiple times depending on your setup. You could initialize using a static initializor instead, or remove the static keyword and use it as an instance variable of the class using the existing configuration:

Example :

```
public class MyTestClass {
    private static String[][] array;

    static {
        array = new String[][] {{"A", "B", "C"},{"D", "E", "F"},{"G", "H", "I"}};
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        // use 'array'
        // but the data might be corrupted
    }
}
```

Or,

```
public class MyTestClass {
    private String[][] array;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        array = new String[][] {{"A", "B", "C"},{"D", "E", "F"},{"G", "H", "I"}};
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        // use 'array'
        // but the data might be corrupted
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I can't use a static block because the code is inside a try block.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **final** keyword in the declaration.

You can also use **ITestContext** here is an exaple http://www.ontestautomation.com/using-the-testng-itestcontext-to-create-smarter-rest-assured-tests/

```
public class MyTestClass {
    private static final String[][] array;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        array = new String[][] {{"A", "B", "C"},{"D", "E", "F"},{"G", "H", "I"}};
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        // use 'array'
        // but the data might be corrupted
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get a compilation error making this variable final.